# GI Load questions

Tags: diabetes

1. What is the proper way to  calculate the glicymic load for a multi-ingredient item? 11 grams sugar, 9 grams protein, etc.
   Do you add all the items' GI load number to each other for a grand total?
2. Would a cup of water before eating sugar lower the GI load?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Glycemic load is calculated](http://www.diabetes.co.uk/diet/glycemic-load.html) on the amount of carbohydrate with a known glycemic index. You can't therefore calculate a glycemic load for different foods with differing indices. Diabetics instead calculate the total amount of carbohydrate in a meal, and may adjust based on fat and protein present in order to work out their insulin dose.